# How to prevent Apache web server accepting requests from unknown hosts

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app running on Elastic Beanstalk which keeps creating redundant sentry error logs when bots make requests with HOST headers not matching my ALLOWED_HOST Django setting. How do I configure Elastic Beanstalk to stop Apache accepting any request that don't match my host name (e.g [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) ?

There are similar questions on here however they do not explain exactly how to change the Apache configurations during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your security group to block all connections except for your ip. To do this you need to go to `Services->EC2->Security Groups->Your Elastic Beanstalk Security Group` and click `Edit Inbound Rules`.[image: Security Group Screenshot]